# How do I rename an instrument in OpenMPT?

Tags: software, instruments, midi

[image: menu dropdown for Sample Instrument]

How do I rename an instrument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: OpenMpt 1.28.00

have you got this one?

there is a new tab *insturments* between samples and comments.

type in the name. that's it

if not:

go to *comments:*

chose or type the new name in the upper window

select the instrument in the lower window

finished

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather complicated two-phase process that's best explained with the following usage-scenario-logic diagram that applies to at least OpenMPT version 1.27.09.00.

[image: MPT How To Edit Sample Name]